# How can I represent the $-3 Re(z) - 6 Im(z) \geq -2$ and $Re(z) > 2$ on a complex number plane?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

How can I represent the $-3 Re(z) - 6 Im(z) \geq -2$ and $Re(z) > 2$ on a complex number plane?

Is it just $-3 - 6 * i \geq -2$ and $x >2$?

Comment: by $x>2$ you mean $\Re(z)>2?$

Comment: Take $z=x+iy$ whence Re(z)=x, Im(z)=y Now, you have two inequalities:  $-3x-6y\ge -2$ and $x\gt 2$ You can't write $-3-6i\ge -2$ because order property (greater than, less than) is not defined for imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the complex plane, a plot of $x$ and $y$ is made where the complex number $z$ can is written as $z=x+iy \ \ \ (x,y \in \mathbb{R})$

So $\Re(z)=x$ and $\Im(z)=y$

Thus the inequalities are :

$$-3x-6y \geq -2$$

$$x > 2$$

These regions are easy to interpret in a cartesian system:

[image]

[Here is a link to the Desmos page of the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/phss4muldn)